# SQL selecting multiple record by different variable

Tags: sql, join, records

Ok, so I have a table `Assignment`:

```
[UserId]
[GroupId]
[UpdatedBy]
[UpdatedAt]
```

Also, I have a function for returning users from a specific group:

```
select UserId 
from dbo.GetGroupUsers() ggu 
where ggu.GroupId = ?
```

In `Assignment`, I want to check all groups that our user is listed and then I want to select ALL users from these groups, without duplicate.

How can I achieve this?

Edit:
Sample output form selecting groupid = 4
[image: sample_output]

for example user "test1" belong to other group where id=2 at the same time and i want selected all users from for example group 2 and 4 (cause in this example test1 said so) without records duplicate

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: What's the structure of `Group`?

Comment: @stickybit sorry for misguiding, everything is in Assignments

Comment: @D-Shih edited post with sample

Comment: @maciejlacwik From your edit question I still don't know your logic sorry

Comment: Still unclear. Your sample output has more columns than your [Assignment] table. How many tables are you dealing with exactly besides the [Assignment] table?

Comment: mayby in that way:

I have a user, my user is belonging to 3 diffrent groups at the same time. Having this user's ID i can select all these groups. Now, from these groups i want to select all users, that these groups contains, ofc without duplication.

Sorry for my english, it needs to be improved

Comment: You are not clear. Use enough words & sentences to say what you mean. Please read & act on [mcve]. Please clarify by post edits, not comments. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what can't be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Answer (score 1):

All groups from one UserId (say UserId 10):

```
select GroupId from Assignment where UserId = 10
```

Select all users from those groups (without duplicate):

```
select distinct UserId 
from dbo.GetGroupUsers() ggu 
where ggu.GroupId in (select GroupId from Assignment where UserId = 10)
```

I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: basically yup, i know this is trivial but after 20h of work my brain is just blackbox

Comment: Glad I was able to help

Answer (score 0):

An inner self join should get you the IDs of the users you're looking for. Join the result with your user table (which you didn't post) to possibly get other information about these users.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       a2.userid
       FROM assignment a1
            INNER JOIN assignment a2
                       ON a2.groupid = a1.groupid
       WHERE a1.userid = ?;
```

(Replace the `?` with the ID of the user, you want to start with.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is a user id:test1 and assuming that you are just looking at one table (Assignment)

```
DECLARE @UserId INT = 2
;WITH GROUPS AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT GroupId FROM Assignment WHERE UserId = @UserId 
)
SELECT distinct assgn.UserName, gps.GroupId FROM Assignment assgn
INNER JOIN
GROUPS gps ON
assgn.GroupId = gps.GroupId
```

Please let me know if this helps